# Meaning using lay in English

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

> She lay on her back under the tree. The tree had broad leaves under which she lay.

What the above sentence mean?

Writer wanted to describe that she was already laying under the tree at some point of time? Or her action of laying at some point of time? Or lying under tree is her everyday or routine activity?

Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

They are both somewhat ambiguous. The natural meaning of both is that she was in a lying position at the time referred to: if it referred to her change of position, *lay down* would be more likely.

However, with suitable context, both could have the "action" meaning, for example: *She went out into the garden. She lay on her back under the tree, and went to sleep.*

Similarly, your third, "habitual" meaning is not excluded, but would require context to establish it: *She used to take a nap in the afternoon. She lay on her back under the tree.*

Note that in your third and fourth lines, the standard word is "lying": "laying" is part of the transitive verb "lay" (= "put something flat on a surface"). Having said that, many people do use "lay" and "laying" in this sense; but it is not standard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I totally agree with your answer. Only why cant it be repetative past . Simple past is also used as would or Use to. Mainly to discribe habitts.

Comment: @user4084: I said that it could be habitual, but it would require context to establish that.

Comment: I really do not think "she lay on her back under a tree" is ambiguous at all. I see no reason to complicate this. In a short story, for instance, it would describe a past, once-off event. And in that sense is perfectly logical. The actual sentence as given was not, it seems understood by the OP. Simple past describes past events that are not longer.

Comment: Sorry, @Lambie, I disagree (again!). _He came into the garden and saw Ellen resting. She lay on her back under the tree_ is a perfectly cromulent narrative where it has stative meaning.

Comment: @Colin Fine He **came*** into the garden, **saw**, **lay**: That is ambiguous? It is the simple past used in narration.  How can any of that be ambiguous? In the OP's sentence there is only one action. Obviously, "She used to play tennis, and she played again recently" is not the same. We seem to be crossing wires. Why try to tease out every possible thing when it's not in the OP's context. One can transform just about anything into something else....

Comment: @Lambie, I took it that the OP was asking which aspect _lay_ had in those examples, and I believe that it could have any of them with suitable context. Since the context was not given, I answered that it could be any of them.

Comment: @Colin Fine I do not understand why saying it is narrative descriptive past is not sufficient.

Comment: @Lambie: you said it was narrative descriptive past. I didn't and neither did the OP.

Comment: @Colin  Fine Yes, I did. I try to explain what is the easiest in terms of the post and not come up with every single verb form possible (used to etc.). The question was about this specific use of lay, and here, functionally, it is clearly narrating a past event.

Comment: @Lambie: I don't find it clear. It could be an action, but I would expect _lay down_ in that case. I find the sentences quoted more natural with a stative meaning. The very fact that you and I disagree on this indicates that there can be doubt.

Comment: In US English, lay is the past of lie, as in: She lay in the hay, singing. Just like: She stood in the hay, singing. Also, the second sentence is had.

Comment: In British English too. _Lie_, like _sit_ and _stand_ can have active or stative meanings.I have no idea what "the second sentence is had" means.